# 100% CPU USAGE: MySQL 2,000,000 rows and query with LIKE operator

Tags: php, mysql, search, cpu-usage, lag

I have a `MySQL` table with 2,000,000 rows, my website has 40.000 to 50.000 visits per day, PHP running 150 queries per second in total, and the MySQL CPU usage is around 90%. The website is extremely slow.

Dedicated Server: AMD Opteron 8 cores, 16 GB DDR3.

Here are the MYSQL query details:

```
Search Example: Guns And Roses
Table Storage Engine: MyISAM

Query example:

SELECT SQL_CACHE mp3list.*, likes.* FROM mp3list
   LEFT JOIN likes ON mp3list.mp3id = likes.mp3id
   WHERE mp3list.active=1 AND mp3list.songname LIKE '%guns%'
   AND mp3list.songname LIKE '%and%' AND mp3list.songname LIKE '%roses%'
   ORDER BY likes.likes DESC LIMIT 0, 15"
```

Column "songname" is `VARCHAR(255)`.

I want to know what I have to do to implement a lighter mysql search, if someone could help me, I'll be always grateful, I'm looking for a solution for weeks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Rômulo, `mp3list` & `likes` create statements would help us, too.

Comment: If everything else fails, have look at Solr.

Comment: i would move to a more  scalable hosting environment like AWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one solution would be to stop using a performance killer like `like '%something%'`.

One way we've done this in the past is to maintain our own lookup tables. By that I mean, put together insert, update and delete triggers which apply any changes to a table like:

```
word      varchar(20)
id        int references mp3list(id)
primary key (word,id)
```

Whenever you make a change to `mp3list`, it gets reflected to that table, which should be a lot faster to search than your current solution.

This moves the cost of figuring out what MP3s contain what words to when you *update,* rather than every time you `select`, amortising the cost. Since the vast majority of databases are read far more often than written, this can give substantial improvements. Some DBMS' provide this functionality with a full text search index (MySQL is one of these).

And you can even put some smarts in the triggers (and queries) to totally ignore noise words like `a`, `an` and `the`, saving both space and time, giving you more fine-grained control over what you want to store.

Comment: Or just use fulltext search?

Comment: @eggyal, yes, though being a true multi-platform bod, I tend to prefer being able to move easily between the platforms. If you're going to stick with MySQL (and don't want the full control over what words are stored), by all means use the full text index - it's no doubt easier to implement than a manual solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I've decided to use fulltext.